# How to set up Joomla! 4 properly

Tags: installation, git, joomla-4.x, github

I'm trying to do a pull request for Joomla! 4.

I've downloaded the repro and changed branch but now I need a working copy of J4 so I can test my code.

I try to install it the usual way but it the following message appears:

> **Environment Setup Incomplete**
>
> It looks like you are trying to run
> Joomla! from our git repository. To do so requires you complete a
> couple of extra steps first.

I've completed the actions on this page: https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J4.x:Setting_Up_Your_Local_Environment

I believe the problem relates to **node.js**.  But I can't prove it.  I did see an error previously but it no longer shows.  **npm ci** seems to work fine.  **Composer** seems to work fine too.

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download and install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) first.

Once done, open your terminal, navigate to the root of your Joomla installtion, and type in the following command:

```
composer install
```

You'll then need to install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Once installed, in the same terminal, run the following command:

```
npm i
```

These commands will fetch all the Joomla PHP dependencies, Javascript dependencies, compile all ES6 Javascript and put the files in their appropriate locations

You should then be able to install Joomla

Comment: `composer install` works
`npm ci` works, `npm i` works, `npm install -g npm@lts` works.  Installing node manually also works.  but I still get the same message consistently.  

Perhaps this was a temporary glitch and I should use the latest nightly, I'll try that.

Comment: Is cloning from GitHub the same as downloading a nightly build?

Comment: Also, when I submitted my Pull it went to J4, which I didn't want.  So I need to make sure I'm on the J4 branch to commit.  Which I understand.  I initially cloned github.com/joomla-cms then I changed branch in PHP Storm to J4.  Then I tried to push, but I couldn't because I don't have permissions.  How would I clone joomla-cms, change branch, then fork it to create my new branch that I can push to which is on my own Github account?

Comment: Not quite. Joomla's Github repo doesnt contain all of the PHP and JS dependencies, whereas all the proper downl9adable builds do. So cloning the repo requires the 2 commands stated in my answer.

Comment: You need to fork, then clone, then switch branch. Dont clone the official repo. Clone your fork instead

Comment: Thanks for your help Lodder.  And sorry for so many questions, hopefully they help someone else.  So I need to fork using the Github UI and then access it via PHP Storm right?

Comment: I dont use the UI or PHP Storm but I believe that's correct